Executable/installable files with electron FE and python BE
I have a problem with my current project.
I have a backend written in python which i complain with pyinstaller to an exe.
The py BE communicate with websockets with the FE written in JS/hmtl/css.
I got it working the I can compile with electron everything together to an installer for windows and mac (so no browser version, standalone exe) but somehow, I can not get it done anymore and don't find the guide/docs which I used in the first time.
I know there are couple of ways to get it done like with child processes etc but I'd like to use a compiled version of the py code again (planning to obfuscate it in future).
If anyone could explain, how I have to compile everything (so py .exe with the JS/hmtl/css FE) to an installer, I'd highly appreciate it!
If you need more information, please lmk! I recently started coding, therefore please bare with me :D

If I well understood you question, you want to build an installer for windows and mac from your electron application with python exe as backend. I will talk only about windows since it has been tested.
You can use electron-builder to do so.
You will need to tell electron-builder to take your python exe as an extra ressource while building, to do so, lets suppose you put your python exe in a directory called python_scripts you can add that at you build section in package.json :
    "extraResources": [
          {
          "./python_scripts/**",
        ],
}

then for windows you have to decide which target you want to build, windows installer in your case :
"win": {
      "target": [
        "nsis"
      ],
}

More options here : https://www.electron.build/win
Finally to effectively build, you will need to pass a commande that look like that :
npm run build && electron-builder build --win --publish never && npm run build:dll

Where build and build:dll commands look like below :
 1. "build": "concurrently \"npm run build:main\" \"npm run
    build:renderer\""
 2. "build:dll": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development TS_NODE_TRANSPILE_ONLY=true webpack --config
    <your-webpack-config-file>

